# CSS button positioning - fiddle included

Tags: css

I have the following fiddle which includes a snippet of the HTML I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/UQGs6/

Basically this is part of a wizard screen that I'm trying to incorporate.  I'm using the stepy wizard plugin.  But my question is about the buttons.  I would like to have the buttons display in the same location for every screen.  I made the height of the fieldset.step = 475px.

I want my buttons to be closer to the bottom.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/UQGs6/1/

Additional css:

```
fieldset.step {position:relative}
#default-buttons-0 {position:absolute;bottom:15px;right:15px}
```

Comment: I understand what the absolute is doing (I tried that initially).  However I don't understand the fieldset.step {position:relative}.  Why does that make it work?

Comment: Absolute positioning needs a context. If no context is defined, the element is positioned in relation to the body element. In your context it was clear for me that the context of the button should be the fieldset