# CSS - Button separation

Tags: css

I asked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861721/css-button-positioning-fiddle-included) earlier and @topek answered it perfectly.  However, I thought I would be able to split the buttons (float: right and float: left), however, my efforts to do so failed.

Basically in addition to the buttons showing up at the bottom of the div in the same location through the entire wizard process I would also like the buttons to show up on either side of the fieldset.  I should note that there is a beginning wizard screen that only includes the "Next >" button (a href) and an ending screen that contains a "< Back" button (a href) and an input button "Finish".  I would like the "Next >" button to show on the right hand side always (as well as the "Finish").

Please see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HcAVX/

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply position your buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/HcAVX/1/

Comment: topek to the rescue again!  Awesome.  So just so I understand.  The reason why this worked was because we did set the position to absolute for the "default-buttons" class then we added all the <a> tags as well then the Left and Right position worked.  Is that correct?

Comment: In the new fiddle instead of positioning the button container we simply position the a elements. It's the same as before but now two elements are positioned seperatly.

Comment: yes but you also added the "a" to this: .default-buttons a{position:absolute;bottom:15px;} - My question I guess is because you added the "a" to this line it allowed for use to position the buttons individually.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the line means the same as this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/HcAVX/2/ - it's just shorter.